# How do I make html body tag's 16 px to be 62.5% so that px to em conversion becomes easier?

Tags: html, css

I read on Quora the following:

> By setting the font-size of the  (which by default its 16px) to
>   62.5%, setting em based font-sizes for the rest of the page becomes very simple. just divide the intended pixel size by 10 to get the
>   equivalent size in ems.
>
> 10px = 1.0 em 11px = 1.1em 12px = 1.2em

How does this work and how do i achieve this?

Comment: Relevant - https://css-tricks.com/css-font-size/ (maybe the ultimate source of the Quora..)

Comment: Interesting - not sure if this has changed since http://stackoverflow.com/a/1751056/

Answer (score 3):

This is what I use.

```
html { font-size: 62.5%; }
```